# Safe way to read overflowed double as 'inf' from string

Tags: c++, double, ieee-754

Is there a nice way to read `double` from string with respect of overflowing, i.e. convert `"1e500" -> +inf` ?

The ways to read from string I am aware of:

- `::std::stringstream` - returns garbage on overflow;
- `::boost::lexical_cast` - thrown bad_lixecal_cast with no worthy information about the number being converted
- `::std::strtod` from `cstdlib` - afaik it is the only one that reports about overflows (by returning `HUGE_VAL` and setting `errno` to `ERANGE`), but using it is quiet inconvenient

Particularly I need a method to reliably convert string to number (`double`), e.g.

```
"1e100" -> 1e100
"1e300" -> 1e300
"1e309" -> +inf // handling overflow as ieee-754 'inf'
```

EDIT:

I'm actually using the last approach, here is code:

```
double stringToDouble(char const *str)
{
    double result = ::std::strtod(str, 0);

    if (ERANGE == errno)
    {
        if (HUGE_VAL == result)
        {
            result = INFINITY;
        }
        else if (-HUGE_VAL == result)
        {
            result = -INFINITY;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I was rather surprised that `stringstream` doesn't handle overflow nicely. But it actually returns some other `double` value (unrelated to one being read), and reports only by stream::fail() means.

But still I'm looking for some C++-way number reading.

Comment: OK, use strtod, wrap the incovenience in a function, and the inconvenience is gone, no?

Comment: are you sure there is no way to make istringstream report an error somehow for those numbers? What exactly is the garbage it returns?

Comment: @John: True, but how about providing a code sample?  It might be obvious to you, but it's not obvious to the OP, or he wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure you're correct. But in any case I am only commenting, not providing an answer. If the OP requests some code, I'll gladly give it.

Comment: @john I'm actually using this solution right now, but I was looking for some C++-way

Comment: `strtod(txt, NULL)` does it conveniently. how do you expect the method to behave in case the string doesn't represent a valid double?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your current C way of doing things is a lot more efficient than what I'm about to suggest, but since you're asking for a C++ method, here is one by defining a manipulator-like object to protect you from overflows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct OverflowProtect
{
} limitdouble;

struct DoubleOverflowException : public std::exception
{

};

double stringToDouble(char const *str)
{
  double result = ::std::strtod(str, 0);

  if (ERANGE == errno)
  {
    if (HUGE_VAL == result)
    {
      throw DoubleOverflowException(); // throw whatever exception you want here
    }
    else if (-HUGE_VAL == result)
    {
      throw DoubleOverflowException(); // throw whatever exception you want here
    }
  }

  return result;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & aIn, const OverflowProtect & aManip)
{
  string number;
  aIn >> number;

  stringToDouble(number.c_str());

  for_each(number.rbegin(), number.rend(), [&aIn](char c){aIn.putback(c);});

  return aIn;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{  
  double nr;
  try
  {
    cin >> limitdouble >> nr;
  }
  catch ( DoubleOverflowException & e )
  {
    // handle overflow exception thrown by limitdouble
    e;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Not the most efficient way, especially the `operator>>` implementation, but undoubtedly C++-like, and a lot of fun.
I'm sure improvements can be made, I am just illustrating an idea.

Comment: well, it sure is a lot of fun. :)